# MySQL ошибка 39

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

при попытке удалить базу через phpmyadmin вылетает ошибка:
**"#1010 - Error dropping database (can't rmdir './students', errno: 39)'"**
как удалять такую "застрявшую" базу?
используется ubuntu 15.04 и xampp 5.6.12-0

Comment: похожая проблема: [тыц](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196996/mysql-error-dropping-database-errno-13-errno-17-errno-39)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Зашел в каталог */opt/lampp/var/mysql* и удалил вручную папку *students* - по названию моей базы, после чего добавил её через *phpMyAdmin* снова, даже не останавливая сервис *MySQL*.